# can you create space between background image repeats?

Tags: css, background-image, space, background-repeat

Is it possible to repeat a background image, but specify a number of pixels before the next repeat starts.

i.e.    background: url(img.png) *[after 40px]* repeat-x;

I don't want to add empty space to the image.

Comment: Only way will be with images, which you don't want to add sasdly.

Comment: No I have atleast a couple of hundred kilobytes of images just to make a virtual landscape then I have animated clouds a Forest, a fence but a lot of my audience will be in Georgian republic hence slowish Internet at times and don't want to overdo it when whats important is the content. I had to make a sacrifice and suffer the restrictions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
background-repeat: space;
background-repeat: round; // round(520 / 100) = round(5.2) = 5
```

The browser will render five images in the space but adjust the image width to 104px (520px / 5). The image is made wider to fit the container. [Full details here](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-background-repeat-space-round/) 
or read 
[Background Size property](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-background-size-property/)

Comment: Unfortunately, background-repeat space and round values are not yet supported on major browsers. This is from the article you reffered to:
> "Two browsers support the space and round properties. Guess which ones? You’re wrong: it’s IE9 and Opera. At the time of writing, they are not implemented in Firefox, Chrome or Safari. It gets worse:

    When Firefox encounters space or round it falls back to repeat.
    When Chrome or Safari encounter space or round they fall back to no-repeat. In addition, the webkit browsers appear to recognize the properties but don’t render them correctly."