# Create space between repeat background images - HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply background images to my application, i need to add space between the repeat images, my code is below

```
#wrapper {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative; 
    background-image: url(../images/background.png) repeat;
}
```

i need to apply white space before starting repeat images in CSS.
please anyone give me an idea to do this

Comment: You can't in css, try to add the space on photoshop. Just a padding transparent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199863/can-you-create-space-between-background-image-repeats) OR [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875466/css-background-repeat-distance)

Comment: You can add space attribute https://www.impressivewebs.com/space-round-css3-background/

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in `CSS`. I think it's better to edit the image in photoshop and add some transparant paddings to the sides of the image. If that doesn't work then add a white space on each side of the image in the width you prefer.